# Passing in an existing variable into a Ruby method

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver, pageobjects, page-object-gem

I'm trying to write a test to make sure existing users can't register (Using Cucumber, Watir-Webdriver and Page Objects)

I have the following code:

```
  text_field(:email, :id => "user_email")
  text_field(:password, :id => "user_password")
  text_field(:password_confirmation, :id => "user_password_confirmation")
  checkbox(:terms_privacy, :id => "user_accepts_terms")
  button(:sign_up_button, :text => "Sign Up")

  def unique_username 
    @username = "qa_automation"+"#{rand(6 ** 6)}"+"@gmail.com"
  end  

  def sign_up
    unique_username
    self.email = @username
    self.password = USERS['PASSWORD']
    self.password_confirmation = USERS['PASSWORD']
    self.check_terms_privacy
    self.sign_up_button
    puts "username: #{@username}"
    @existing = @username
  end   

  def sign_up_with_existing_account
    puts "exisiting username: #{@existing}"
    self.email = @exisiting
    self.password = USERS['PASSWORD']
    self.password_confirmation = USERS['PASSWORD']
    self.check_terms_privacy
    self.sign_up_button
    puts "username: #{@existing}"
  end
```

But the @existing variable is returning nothing. These two lines are giving me back nothing:

```
puts "exisiting username: #{@existing}"
self.email = @exisiting
```

So I guess I'm trying to figure out how to pass the @existing variable from the 'sign_up' method to the 'sign_up_with_existing_account' method? Thoughts?

Comment: There is a typo in 'exisiting'

Comment: I think you need to show how you are using the page object (likely the Cucumber steps). In particular, are you calling `sign_up` and `sign_up_with_existing_account` on the same instance?

Comment: @JustinKo Like this in my step defs:
  
  on_page(RegistrationNew).sign_up

  on_page(RegistrationNew).sign_up_with_existing_account

Comment: That will create two different instances of the RegistrationNew page. The `@existing` will only be set in the first instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't and should not want to do that. Testing would be a tangled mess if running one test could affect the result of another. You should set up the existing user ahead of time (using e.g. `Before`) so that any test that needs an existing user can take advantage of it.